# If $f\left(x\right)=$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $\frac{x^{3n}}{\left(3n\right)!}$ then prove $f''\left(x\right)+f'\left(x\right)+f\left(x\right)=e^{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> **Question**If $f\left(x\right)=$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$$\frac{x^{3n}}{\left(3n\right)!}$
>   then prove that

$f''\left(x\right)+f'\left(x\right)+f\left(x\right)=e^{x}$

**My Approach**$f\left(x\right)=$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$$\frac{x^{3n}}{\left(3n\right)!}$

$f'\left(x\right)=$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$$\frac{x^{3n-1}}{\left(3n-1\right)!}$
=$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$$\frac{x^{3n+2}}{\left(3n+2\right)!}$

$f''\left(x\right)=$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}$$\frac{x^{3n-2}}{\left(3n-2\right)!}$
=$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$$\frac{x^{3n+4}}{\left(3n+4\right)!}$

$f''\left(x\right)+f'\left(x\right)+f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n}}{\left(3n\right)!}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+2}}{\left(3n+2\right)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+4}}{\left(3n+4\right)!}$

Now i am unable to prove it to be equal to $e$$^{x}$

Comment: Surely the r.h.s. should be $e^x$, not $e$.

Comment: @Travis it was a typo ,i fixed it. Can you please elaborate

Comment: $$\sum_1^\infty\frac{x^{3n-1}}{(3n-1)!}=\frac{x^2}2+\cdots$$
$$\sum_2^\infty\frac{x^{3n+2}}{(3n+2)!}=\frac{x^8}{40320}+\cdots$$
???

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is generally ok, but for $f''$ we should rewrite it like below:
$f''=(f')'=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+2}}{\left(3n+2\right)!})'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{\left(3n+1\right)!}$

So finally, we will have:
$f\left(x\right)+f'\left(x\right)+f''\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n}}{\left(3n\right)!}+\frac{x^{3n+2}}{\left(3n+2\right)!}+\frac{x^{3n+1}}{\left(3n+1\right)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}=e^x$

Note that as we had all $3n, 3n+1$ and $ 3n+2$, we could merge those 3 sigmas.

Comment: when you differentiated $f'\left(x\right)$

then i think in $f''\left(x\right)$summation should start from n=1

Comment: @MohanSharma: the answer above is right: take attention at the difference between $(3n-1)$ and $(3n+2)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write: $$f(x) = 1 + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} + \ldots $$ and $$f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n+2}}{(3n+2)!}$$ $$ = \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \ldots$$ $$f''(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!} $$ $$= x + \frac{x^4}{4!} +\ldots$$

Add them up to get $e^x$.

Comment: Brother is there any method to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n}}{\left(3n\right)!}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+2}}{\left(3n+2\right)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+4}}{\left(3n+4\right)!}$
=$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{\left(n!\right)}$
By summation tricks?

Comment: @MohanSharma There are two mistakes. One is that $$f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{x^{3n+2}}{(3n+2)!}$$ Another one is that differentiating the above result then gives us: $$f''(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!}$$

Comment: @MohanSharma Now, note that there are only three possible remainders $\bmod 3$ : the set $\{0,1,2\}$. Now, note that all powers of $x$ are covered in $$f(x) +f'(x) +f''(x) $$ so the sum as you get is $e^x$.

Comment: Are you sure that $f''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!}$

Comment: $f''(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!}$

replacing n$\rightarrow n+1$

$f''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+4}}{(3n+4)!}$

Comment: Please tell me how you are getting $n=1$.. I have showed you that the index should be $n=0$.

Comment: I think when we differentiate the lower index moves one digit forward.I may be wrong but i observed this through many questions

Comment: No, @MohanSharma Note that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n-1}}{(3n-1)!}$$ doesn't make sense. Why!? Because $n=0$ gives an undefined quantity. But, if there is a $(3n+1)!$ term, do we have any problem in defining the $n=0$ term? No!!!

Comment: The design of question is based on this fact that any   $n  ∈   N $ can be written as $n≡r mod 3; r= 0, 1, 2$ and that all kind of numbers like $3n, 3n+1 and 3n+2 $appears in exponents of x and in factorials in denominator of f(x), f'(x) and f"(x).

Comment: i did not wrote $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n-1}}{(3n-1)!}$
You can see that $f'\left(x\right)$= $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n-1}}{(3n-1)!}$
lower index is n=1 not n=0

Comment: If f$\left(x\right)$$=\sum_{n=0}^{k}$x$^{n}$= 1+x$^{1}$+x$^{2}+........+x^{k}$

$f'\left(x\right)=$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}$kx$^{k-1}$=1+2x+3x$^{2}$+........+kx$^{k-1}$

Differentiating a power series moves the lower index 1 digit forward